# Error when adding pagination in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I started out with the Spring Boot Database Tutorial but want to add some limits to the SQL Query.

I added Pagination but its giving an error.

I have the following repository class.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.User;

// This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository
// CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Consignment, Integer> {
    Page<Example> findByValidIsTrue(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Error is as below

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.accessingdatamysql.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.accessingdatamysql.UserRepository.findConsignmentsByAccount(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.accessingdatamysql.UserRepository.findConsignmentsByAccount(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! Method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.accessingdatamysql.UserRepository.findConsignmentsByAccount(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable) expects at least 1 arguments but only found 0. This leaves an operator of type SIMPLE_PROPERTY for property account unbound.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.accessingdatamysql.UserRepository.findConsignmentsByAccount(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! Method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.accessingdatamysql.UserRepository.findConsignmentsByAccount(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable) expects at least 1 arguments but only found 0. This leaves an operator of type SIMPLE_PROPERTY for property account unbound.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
at com.example.accessingdatamysql.AccessingDataMysqlApplication.main(AccessingDataMysqlApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
```

Below if the controller used which might be causing the problem. I tried removing the @Autowired but still did not work.

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Controller // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") // This means URL's start with /demo 
public class MainController {
@Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
           // Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to 
handle the data
private UserRepository userRepository;

@PostMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY POST Requests
public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
        , @RequestParam String email) {
    // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
    // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

    return "Saved";
}

@GetMapping(path="/all")
@ResponseBody
public  String getAllUsers() {
    // This returns a JSON or XML with the users

    PageRequest req = PageRequest.of(0,10); // I just want 10 record
    Page<Example> page =  userRepository.findByValidIsTrue(req );
    List<Example> nRecords = page.getContent();

    Gson json = new Gson();
    return json.toJson(nRecords);

}
```

}

Comment: You should extend `PagingAndSortingRepository`

Comment: Still giving error
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.accessingdatamysql.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Chris there will few issue `CrudRepository` does not support Pageable

if Want to use Pagination using Pageable please use `JpaRepository` form **Spring Data**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Example, Integer> {
    Page<Example> findByValidIsTrue(Pageable pageable);
}
```

**Note:-**  you have Provide same Class as return Type Class

Answer (score 0):

You can also you PagingAnsSortingRespository instead.

public interface UserRepository extends PagingAnsSortingRespository<Example, Integer> { Page findByValidIsTrue(Pageable pageable); }

Comment: Same error org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.accessingdatamysql.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method

Comment: cross check your codes again such error is usually related to either autowiring of a class or annotations import

Comment: I removed the Autowired from the controller but its giving error  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.accessingdatamysql.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface org.springframework.data.domain.Example

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to me as a bean creation issue. You can verify the below steps in your code.

1. Base packages added or not in `SpringBootApplication (Main Class)`

   ```
   @EntityScan("com.example.*") //packages for entity classes
   @EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.*")//packages for repo classes
   ```
2. Add `@Repository` and `JpaRepository` to the repository class

   ```
   @Repository
   public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Consignment, Integer> {
     Page<Example> findByValidIsTrue(Pageable pageable);
   }
   ```
3. Verify the `@Configuration` class if present.
4. Entity classes should have `@Entity`, `@Table`.
5. The Primary key `@Id` should be of Integer type in `Consignment` . As mentioned in the interface signature.  `CrudRepository<Consignment, Integer>`